# Load tf.data.Dataset with dynamic batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am wondering if there is a way to load `tf.data.Dataset` with dynamic batch size instead of using fixed size like in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch)?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a custom training loop or `model.fit`?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –

Comment: @AloneTogether I am using custom training loop. The reason why I want dynamic batch size is because I want to train a Graph Neural Networks model and I want 1 batch represents 1 whole graph and they vary in node size.